# Calendar showing previous month

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, calendar, react-date-range

I am using react-date-range to create a Date picker, everything is working great however, when I open the modal it is focused on the previous month not the month of the date.
Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-haze-3tdx9f?file=/src/datepicker.jsx:2948-2958)